# How to use usestate with object in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I am trying to write a simple program that allows you to enter your first and last name in input fields so you get a greeting based on your name. But I cannot get it to work.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [Savedinput, setSavedinput] = useState({Fname:' ' , Lastname:''} );
  const ChangeFirst = (e) => {
    setSavedinput Savedinput.Fname(e.target.value);
  };
  const ChangeLast = (e) => {
    setSavedinput Savedinput.Lastname(e.target.value);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="Text" onChange={ChangeFirst}></input>
      <input type="Text" onChange={ChangeLast}></input>

      <h1> hello  {Fname} {Lastname}  </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have 2 states for firstName and lastName

```
export default function App() {
  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="Text" value={firstName} onChange={() => setFirstName(e.target.value)}></input>
      <input type="Text" value={lastName} onChange={() => setLastName(e.target.value)}></input>

      <h1> hello  {firstName} {lastName}  </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: add `e` inside the `onChange` function parameter like: `onChange={(e) => setFirstName(e.target.value)}` @Osama

Answer (score 2):

You can use destructure method.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [Savedinput, setSavedinput] = useState({Fname:' ' , Lastname:''} );
  const onInputChange = (e, attr) =>{
      setSavedinput({...Savedinput, [attr]: e.target.value});
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="Text" onChange={(e)=>{onInputChange(e, 'Fname)}} value={Savedinput.Fname}></input>
      <input type="Text" onChange={(e)=>{onInputChange(e, 'Lastname)}} value={Savedinput.Lastname}></input>

      <h1> hello  {Savedinput.Fname} {Savedinput.Lastname}  </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Really nice example of clean form processing in React. Smart to use only one change handler instead of separate ones.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't [mutate state directly](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/)

To change the a state object you can use [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). So your code would be something like:

```js
  const ChangeFirst = (e) => {
    setSavedinput({...SavedInput, Fname: e.target.value})
  };

  const ChangeLast = (e) => {
    setSavedinput({...SavedInput, Lastname: e.target.value})
  };
```

The `{...SavedInput}` will expand the whole object to the argument and then adding the `Fname: ...` will overwrite that so the new value will be passed instead.

For more advance usage of form I recommend you to use [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com)

Comment: @osama the respective `Fname` and `Lastname` is the property you set in `useState({Fname: "", Lastname: ""})`. and object property can't be undefined. If you changed your input base on other answer please revert to the code from your question, I based my answer from that code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="Text" onChange={ChangeFirst}></input>
<input type="Text" onChange={ChangeLast}></input>
```

use two states

```
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')

const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
```

then respectively on your method use the setState for each of them separately

Answer (score 0):

Firstly the **setSavedinput** is a function and not a variable. It's a function to set the value of the variable used with it. Since you are taking the value from input field the following method might work out for you.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
      const [Savedinput, setSavedinput] = useState({Firstname:'' , Lastname:''} );
        return (
            <div className="App">
              <input type="text" value={Savedinput.Firstname} onChange={(e)=>setSavedinput({... Savedinput , Firstname:e.target.value })} />
              <input type="text" value={Savedinput.Lastname} onChange={(e)=>setSavedinput({... Savedinput , Lastname:e.target.value })} />

      <h1> hello  {Firstname} {Lastname}  </h1>
    </div>
```

Instead of declaring a function , you can do it inline **for this purpose** .
Also I would suggest you to keep the variable names in an order. This is gonna you a lot.

Comment: ./src/App.js
SyntaxError: C:\Users\Osama\Desktop\test\src\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (10:10)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for the object and ...savedinput to maintain the existing object with updating only changed value

```
export default function App() {
const [savedinput, setSavedinput] = useState({firstname:"", 
lastname:""});

 function ChangeFirst  (e) {
 savedinput.firstname = e
 setSavedinput({...savedinput})
 };

 function ChangeLast(e) {
 savedinput.lastname = e
 setSavedinput({...savedinput})
 };

return (
 <div className="App">

  <input type="Text" onChange={event => 
   ChangeFirst(event.target.value)}></input>

  <input type="Text" onChange={event => 
  ChangeLast(event.target.value)}>.  
   </input>

  <h1> hello  {savedinput.firstname }{savedinput.lastname}   </h1>
  </div>
  );
   }
```

You can find this working in this [link](https://snack.expo.dev/@ruchi_react/objectstate)